# I have a requirement where in "onclick" of a button I need to attach all files in Notes & Attachments

Tags: custom-button, attachment

I have a requirement where in "onclick" of a button in Salesforce I need to open a new mail in outlook and attach all attachments available in "Notes & Attachments" related list. Is it possible?

By using URL link `mailto:{!Contact.Email}` I can open up an outlook with To addressed to Contact Email, Similarly can I attach all files in Notes & Attachments to that mail?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using a mailto link but could write a VF page that allows a user to specify the body, to and subject text for an email which you can then send using the [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) class attaching all the files using apex.